# Recovering From Safe Mode

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, safe-mode

I changed the boot settings of my VM to safe mode, but I forgot to keep networking on. Now, I can't connect to it. How do I fix this?

Comment: Reboot? Revert to the snapshot you should have taken before you started this? Create a new instance and move your data over?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this command :

```
gcloud compute instances network-interfaces update NAME_INSTANCE --zone=ZONE_INSTANCE
```

Or just stop the instance, enter to its settings, and remove and add a new nic, once started, the network should be up again.

Or, you can stop the instance, and in the edit page, allow serial port connection, and re enable the network via the serial port.